# Android - "Pausing" SystemClock Timer

Tags: android

First thing's first, here is my code:

```
public class MyClass extends Activity {

private Runnable updateTask = new Runnable() {  
    public void run() {
        now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        elapsed = duration - (now - mStart); //duration = 30000
        if (elapsed > 0) {
            seconds = (int) (elapsed / 1000);
            minutes = seconds / 60;
            seconds     = seconds % 60;

            mHandler.postAtTime(this, now + 1000);
        }
        else {
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(this);
            finish();
        }
    }
};

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mStart = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    mHandler.post(updateTask);

    this.pause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MyClass.this,NextActivity.class);
            MyClass.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTask);
}

public void onRestart(){
    super.onRestart();
    mHandler.post(updateTask);
}
```

I shortened the code to make it a bit easier to read. The timer works fine and the timer is counting down to zero. The problem I'm having is that I'm trying to "pause" the timer when I press the button Pause. The pause button actually starts a new activity where it shows a Pause screen, completely obstructing the current activity. Now I know that there is no pause for SystemClock, so the best I can do is remove the thread running the timer (mHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTask)) in onStop() and then call it to start again in onRestart.

The problem is when onRestart(), the timer is displayed as though it ran in the background during the Pause activity. Let's say I pause at 25 seconds. If I'm in the pause screen for 5 seconds and return back to the main activity, the timer will now display 20 seconds, instead of 25 seconds like it's supposed to. I understand that even though I'm in the pause screen, the SystemClock is still running. I have no clue on how to manipulate the SystemClock values to give me the time where it left off.

I borrowed the timer code off of someone here on StackOverflow and I have no clue what "mStart" and "now" is supposed to do. I have worked on this for about three hours and I still can't figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem I'm having is that I'm trying to "pause" the timer when I press the button Pause.

There isn't a direct way to pause a timer, but you can cancel it and change `mStart` to achieve what you want:

```
this.pause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTask);
        // Start your pause screen
    }
});
```

Then when you want to resume the timer update `mStart` but adjust you calculation to remove any elapsed time.

```
protect void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Move these here from onCreate()
    mStart = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - elapsed;
    mHandler.post(updateTask);
}
```

**Addition**
This bothers me, probably because I'm tired:

```
elapsed = duration - (now - mStart);
if (elapsed > 0) {
```

Because *to me* it is less intuitive than

```
elapsed = now - mStart;
if (elapsed < duration) {
```

But that is just me being picky, use whichever approach makes the most sense to you.

If you use:

```
elapsed = duration - (now - mStart);
```

Then the proper equation (as you pointed out below) is:

```
mStart = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + elapsed - duration
```

---

> I have no clue what "mStart" and "now" is supposed to do.

These two variables are used to calculate how long the timer has been running.

- `now` is now.
- `mStart` is when the timer started.
- `now - mStart` is how long the timer has been running.

Comment: Sam it's almost there! It pauses but it has a very weird behavior now. Let's say the duration is now set to 10000 (10 seconds to make my explanation clearer. I've been debugging like crazy after you gave your solution). Alright the behavior is this: If I pause at 8 seconds and unpause, it displays 1 second. If I pause at 7 seconds and unpause, it displays 2 seconds. Pause at 6 seconds, unpauses at 3. Pause at 5, unpauses at 4. Pause at 4, unpauses at 5. Pause at 3, unpauses at 6. Pause at 2, unpauses at 7. Pause at 1, unpauses at 8.

Comment: That seems to be the inverse of what you want.  Look for an update in the middle of my answer.

Comment: Sam, it's people like you that makes me love computer programming. You've been extremely helpful. The reason why I did elapsed = duration - (now - mStart) is because I wanted the timer to do gown. With your solution of elapsed = now - mStart, the timer goes up. But with your help everything works as it's supposed to. Although the final working solution is mStart = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + elapsed - duration. This makes sense because duration was in the original "equation." Thank you so much again.

Comment: I glad I could help, I must admit I'm tired and my brain couldn't properly calculate `elapsed = duration - (now - mStart)`. Thanks for providing the actual equation, I'll update my answer.